# XSLT - loop for each child node (varying node size)

Tags: xml, xslt, for-loop

I'm trying to display a chapter & verse entry for proper nouns found in certain Bible verses. This will greatly save me time compared to editing HTML files. That's why I started the XML usage in the first place.

I have it to the point where it is looping the correct # of times per occurrence, yet I can't get it to correctly list the XML data correctly.

For a DOM element of pn_book/pn_chptr/token_occurrence, I have elements of verse & verse_path to create links to the corresponding web page files.

Here's an example of one chapter data file & the XSLT code to render the page:

```
<pn_book>
<pn_chptr>
    <bookname>2 John </bookname> 
    <chptr>1</chptr>
    <token_occurrence>
        <pn_token>Christ</pn_token>
        <verse_path>2JO1.HTM#3</verse_path>
        <verse>3</verse>
        <verse_path>2JO1.HTM#7</verse_path>
        <verse>7</verse>
        <verse_path>2JO1.HTM#9</verse_path>
        <verse>9</verse>
    </token_occurrence>

<xsl:for-each select="pn_book/pn_chptr">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="bookname"/> Chapter <xsl:value-of select="chptr"/></h2>
    <xsl:for-each select="token_occurrence">
        <xsl:value-of select="pn_token" /> - <xsl:value-of select="../bookname"/> 
        <xsl:for-each select="verse">
            <a href="{verse_path}"><xsl:value-of select="../../chptr" />:<xsl:value-of select="../verse" /></a>; 
        </xsl:for-each><br />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The result only displays the first entry instead of each one.
I think I need some sort of counter to display the correct array element in the verse() & verse_path() arrays.

I'm trying to use XSLT instead of just JavaScript.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

```
...
<xsl:for-each select="verse">
    <a href="{preceding-sibling::verse_path[1]}"><xsl:value-of select="../../chptr" />:<xsl:value-of select="." /></a>; 
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Or perhaps a little more efficiently:

```
<xsl:template match="pn_book">
    <xsl:for-each select="pn_chptr">
        <xsl:variable name="bookname" select="bookname" />
        <xsl:variable name="chptr" select="chptr" />
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="$bookname"/> Chapter <xsl:value-of select="$chptr"/></h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="token_occurrence">
            <xsl:value-of select="pn_token" /> - <xsl:value-of select="$bookname"/> 
            <xsl:for-each select="verse">
                <a href="{preceding-sibling::verse_path[1]}"><xsl:value-of select="$chptr" />:<xsl:value-of select="." /></a>; 
            </xsl:for-each>
            <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I got a parsing error, even after tweaking it to what I thought would work. I'll be very happy if we can get it to work. Thanks, though.

Comment: It works with the code you posted (after closing the open tags) - see: http://xsltransform.net/94hvTAn